# Call generic string resource programmatically

Tags: android, android-resources

in `strings.xml` I have one resource.

```
<string name="generic_price_with_rupee_symbol">\u20B9 %s</string>
```

This is what I do in Android data binding **that works perfectly**

```
<TextView
      ...
      android:text="@{@string/generic_price_with_rupee_symbol(item.price)}"
      />
```

**Question:**

How to use this resource in java code? As I don't want to make new resource.

I tried

```
textView.setText(getString(R.string.generic_price_with_rupee_symbol) + "100");
```

That gives wrong result and prints `%s` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be written like this -

```
textView.setText(getString(R.string.generic_price_with_rupee_symbol, "100"));
```

Check out [String getString (int resId, 
                Object... formatArgs)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)) from Documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The formatted values should be passed as parameter as second values to [`getString(int, Object..)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)) method

where `Object...` is

> The format arguments that will be used for substitution

so use

```
textView.setText(getString(R.string.generic_price_with_rupee_symbol, "100"));
//                                                                  ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:-

```
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.generic_price_with_rupee_symbol, "100"));
```